# How do I link a set of Button objects to an Image output to form a image slideshow?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I wanted to make use of `ipywidgets` to build a simple app for data entry. To do that I started to make use of the `Button` class defined in `ipywidgets`. The intended result is an image viewer with buttons for accessing the next image and previous image.

I searched through the documentation, but I am unable to link the images to the buttons as described above.

```
btn = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'))
prev_image = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'),
                            description='Prev',
                            icon='backward')
next_image = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'),
                            description='Next',
                            icon='forward')

out = widgets.Output()
list_of_images = os.listdir('images/')

def on_button_clicked(_):
    global list_of_images
    # "linking function with output"
    with out:
        # what happens when we press the button
        clear_output()
        print('Something happens!')


# linking button and function together using a button's method
prev_image.on_click(on_button_clicked)

def show_images(file=os.listdir(fdir):
    display(Image(fdir + file))

img = interactive(show_images) # store it as an interactive widget


grid = GridspecLayout(2, 2)
grid[0, :] = img
grid[1, 0] = prev_image
grid[1, 1] = next_image
grid #display the grid
```

Here, I guess that making use of the `interactive()` method might be causing the issue by making it incompatible. But I honestly don't know how to go about it. I guess that I could make use of `show_images()` to pass buttons as parameters. But again, I am unsure about how to move forward.

I expect the output to come out like [this](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*YQrJiSx2g6GfhkIqK24RUw.png) but the buttons lie below the image instead of using a dropdown menu for iterating through the images, I would like to make use of the `prev_image` and `next_image` to iterate through the images.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this question while I was looking for a similar problem. I leave the answer here just in case anybody else wants something similar. Here's a minimum working code for your example.

You can use `widgets.Output()` object in combination with the `with` keyword to display image contents.

```py
# !pip install ipywidgets
# !jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
import os
from ipywidgets import Button, Box
from IPython.display import display, Image


btn = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'))
prev_image = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'),
                            description='Prev',
                            icon='backward')
next_image = widgets.Button(layout=Layout(width='auto', height='auto'),
                            description='Next',
                            icon='forward')

out = widgets.Output()
# list of images can be url or path to local images:
list_of_images = ["http://via.placeholder.com/200x200", "http://via.placeholder.com/201x201"]
i = 0
image = Image(url=list_of_images[i])
with out:
    display(image)

def on_next_button_clicked(_):
    global i, image, list_of_images
    # "linking function with output"
    with out:
        # what happens when we press the button
        out.clear_output()
        i = (i+1)%len(list_of_images)
        image.url = list_of_images[i]

        display(image)

def on_prev_button_clicked(_):
    global i, image, list_of_images
    # "linking function with output"
    with out:
        # what happens when we press the button
        out.clear_output()
        i = (i-1)%len(list_of_images)
        image.url = list_of_images[i]
        display(image)


# linking button and function together using a button's method
prev_image.on_click(on_prev_button_clicked)
next_image.on_click(on_next_button_clicked)


buttons = Box([prev_image, next_image])
buttons.layout.display = 'flex'
buttons.layout.justify_content = 'center'
image_layout = Box([out])
image_layout.layout.display = 'flex'
image_layout.layout.justify_content = 'center'
display(buttons, image_layout)
```

[image: working-code]

Comment: Is there a way to do it in an object-oriented approach?